# Problemas de traducción (¿y posición?) en la siguiente medalla de etiqueta

Tags: bug, estado-completado

Ésta es la caja que se abre al pulsar sobre la etiqueta de "Siguiente medalla de etiqueta":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que hay algunas cosas que no se ven bien ahí:

- "Obtenla" no debería llevar tilde.
- El título no tiene mucho sentido (parece que debería ser una etiqueta como la de arriba, pero falla al mostrarse)
- La frase se queda sin terminar, debería acabar con el nombre de la etiqueta, ¿no? "[...] que no sean de wiki en la etiqueta de **html5**".

Comment: `Bronce html5 medalla de etiqueta` podría ser `Medalla de bronce en la etiqueta html5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un poco tarde, pero así es como se verá tras la próxima compilación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto, que lo de la frase sin terminar ocurría en toda la red Stack Exchange, no sólo en este sitio, pero en inglés no se notaba ("the (nombre) tag" -> "the tag") :-)

Comment: Nunca es tarde si la dicha es buena